# WCF custom binding throws Audit Failed(4625) Windows Security events

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am building a WCF service application and I am having a problem with Windows Security event 4625 (Audit Failed) being thrown each time my client invokes the service.

For my services I use NetTcpBinding with the following configuration for security:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding
         {
                 MaxBufferSize = 5000000, 
                 MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5000000, 
                 ReaderQuotas = { MaxArrayLength = 5000000, MaxBytesPerRead = 5000000 }
         };
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
```

After building this NetTcpBinding I have the following code to wrap this binding in the CustomBinding so that I can assign the custom IdentityVerifier

```
var bindingElements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
var ssl = bindingElements.Find<SslStreamSecurityBindingElement>();
ssl.IdentityVerifier = new CustomEndpointIdentityVerifier(caCertificateThubprint);
return new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
```

This is done according to this example from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734778(v=vs.110).aspx

The problem is that when I return this custom binding instead of the NetTcpBinding that i create in the first step, each time during the execution of my application I am having the Audit Failed windows event with not many information in the details.
When I return the NetTcpBinding these security events are not thrown.
What makes it event more interesting is that when I run the same code on the computer that is under Active Directory Domain these events are thrown but if I run it on the pc that is not under domain the events are not thrown.

Is anybody able to help, or give any hints?

Comment: your service is self hosted ? if yes try running it in Administrator mode

Comment: It is self hosted and I am running it in Administrator mode.